# Attach Visualforce page as a PDF in Salesforce standard Email Functionality

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, email-template, salesforcedx

I have a requirement to attach the visualforce page as a PDF in salesforce standard Email.
[image]

I have tried to create "Visualforce Email Template" and attach it as a template here.But I could not able select "Visualforce Email Template" here.
[image]. Its not showing the "Visualforce Email Template".

Could anyone Please give me a solution for this.Is there any other solution for this?How to attach the viualforce page as PDF here.

Comment: It is not clear, what you want to do here. Are you trying to send the VF page as an attachment or want to use the VF page as the email template?

Comment: I want to send the VF page as an attachment

Comment: Check this link http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2016/04/18/pdf-attachment-visualforce/ Hope this helps.